# How do I play the animation from the current frame, ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, button

I'm trying to make a personalized pause button for my flash animations.

This the code I have for it so far

```
var paused:Boolean = false;

pause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_PauseUnpause);

function fl_PauseUnpause(event:MouseEvent):void
{

  if(paused=true)
  {
    stop();
    paused=false;
  }

  else
  {
    gotoAndPlay(this.currentFrame);
    paused=true;
  }
}
```

Stopping the animation works just fine, but it will not start again afterwards. It gives no error when run.

Comment: Tip: there is a `play()` method which you can use instead of `gotoAndPlay(currentFrame)`.

Comment: Also your closing `{` in the first if statement is wrong, it should be `}`

Comment: Problem solved! The closing bracket was just a copying error. The `play()` worked as advertised, and changing the `paused=true` to `paused==true` fixed the syntax error. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(paused=true) // this assigns true to paused and if always evaluates to true
```

That has to be :

```
if(paused==true) //or if(paused)
```

No?